# How to get count on MongoDB's Motor driver?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, motorengine

I want to get count with Motor's diver but I  got this error.

`AttributeError: 'AsyncIOMotorCursor' object has no attribute 'count'`

This is my code:

```
await MOTOR_CURSOR.users.find().count()
```

Comment: Haven't used Mongo in quite a while but what about [count_documents](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-tornado/motor_collection.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCollection.count_documents)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MotorCollection.find()](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-tornado/motor_collection.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCollection.find) returns [AsyncIOMotorCursor](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/cursors.html#asynciomotorcursor) and it does not have `count` method. Instead, you should call [MotorCollection.count_documents()](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-tornado/motor_collection.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCollection.count_documents) instead.

```
await db.users.count_documents({'x': 1})
```

Also worth noting that what you're referring to as `MOTOR_CURSOR` is [MotorDatabase](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-tornado/motor_database.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorDatabase) instance, it would preferable to call it a db instance instead of a cursor to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's unacceptably slow. Unlike plain mongo's `count()` which return a result immediately. But the latter isn't seems available via the Motor :|

Comment: @PavelVlasov, the `count()` function is a legacy function that has been deprecated in all MongoDB client interfaces (i.e. `mongo`). It has been replaced by `count_document()` and `estimated_document_count()`. The legacy `count()` is essentially [estimated_document_count()](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_motor_collection.html?#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorCollection.estimated_document_count).